# Equivalent of Request.CreateResponse()

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, httpresponse

What is the equivalent of

```
var newOrder = new OrderViewModel()
{

   Id = orderDetails.Id,
   Name = orderDetails.Service.Name,
   .....
};
```

`Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, newOrder);`

In this format:

```
HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();
response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;
response.ReasonPhrase = "successfully created blablabla";
```

In the `Request.CreateResponse()` I can pass an object. How can I do that with `HttpResponseMessage`?

Want to be able to pass a message (like `ReasonPhrase`) as well, but can't do that with `Request.CreateResponse()`. Or I'm missing something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To pass in an object as response content you can construct `ObjectContent<T>`:

```
response.Content = new ObjectContent<OrderViewModel>(newOrder, 
                                         new JsonMediaTypeFormatter())
```

Other constructors of `ObjectContent`:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh835040(v=vs.118).aspx

Comment: by the way Joanna, does the method `Request.CreateResponse()` also support a custom message like response.ReasonPhrase? Looking at the docs tells me no. maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: @Quoter - not that I know of. You'll need to create your own extension probably.